# split quantities algorithm (stock exchanges order)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a problem where I have multiple (few thousand) quantities that I need to split between a set number of recipients such that each quantity must be split into whole numbers and using the same proportion. 
I need to find an algorighm that implements this reliably and efficiently (dont we all ?:-) )

This is to solve a problem in financial markets (stock exchange orders) where an order might get thousands of "fills" and at the end of the day must be distributed to a few clients while maintaining the order's average price. Here's an example:

Total Order Quantity 37300

Quantities filled by the Stock Exchange

Execution 1. 16700 shares filled at price 75.84

Execution 2. 5400  shares filled at price 75.85

Execution 3. 4900  shares filled at price 75.86

Execution 4. 10300 shares filled at price 75.87

Total 37300 shares filled at average price = (16700*75.84 + 5400*75.85 + 4900*75.86 + 10300*75.87) / 37300 = 75.85235925

Suppose I need to split these quantities between 3 clients such that :

Client1: 15000 shares

Client2: 10000 shares

Client3: 12300 shares

Each execution must be split individually (I can't just take each clients requested quantity priced at average price)

My first thought was to split each proportionately :

Client 1 gets 15000/37300=0.402144772

Client 2 gets 10000/37300=0.268096515

Client 3 gets 12300/37300=0.329758713

Which would lead to

Client1 - 15000     Client2 - 10000     Client3 - 12300
Ratio : 0.402144772 Ratio : 0.268096515 Ratio : 0.329758713

Splits (Sorry about the formatting - this was the best I could do in the Post editor)

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Client 1    | Client 2    | Client 3    | 
+-------------+-------------+-------------+ 
| 6715.817694 | 4477.211796 | 5506.970509 | 
| 2171.581769 | 1447.72118  | 1780.697051 |
| 1970.509383 | 1313.672922 | 1615.817694 |
| 4142.091153 | 2761.394102 | 3396.514745 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Totals:     |             |             |
|       15000 |       10000 |       12300 | 
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The problem with this is that I can't assign fractional quantities to clients so I need a smart algorithm which adjusts the quantities such that the fractional part of these splits is 0. I understand that this may be impossible in many scenarios so this requirement can be relaxed a little bit so that a certain client gets a little more (or less).

Does anybody know of an algorithm that I can use as a starting point for this problem ?

Comment: This question seems to have a bit too large of a scope for stackoverflow.  Solving the entire problem is really a bit too much to ask.  If, when you are working on this problem, you come across a more specific question it is more likely to be appropriate for this site.

Comment: @Servy, too large? I think if it would have been worded as "how to split 41 in 7 about equal parts so each get whole number like 6,6,6,6,6,6,5?" it would not get so many downvotes...

Comment: Yeah, that's what you get for posting too much info :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round all the numbers (ratio[n] * totalQuantity) except the last one (possibly the smallest) The last one must be the totalQuantity - sum of the others.  This will give you whole number quantities while having a correct total as close to the ratios you choose.

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks. I'm still curious as to whether or not the rounding errors would build up to the point where  average prices are not longer consistent

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this from a different angle. You already know how many shares each client is getting. You want to calculate what's the fair total amount each has to pay and do this without rounding errors.

You therefore want this total *dollar amounts* to have no rounding issues, i.e. be accurate to the 0.01.

Prices can then be computed using the dollar amounts and displayed to the required precision.

The opposite (calculate prices, then derive amounts) will always yield rounding issues with the dollar amounts.

Assuming price is per 100 units, here's one way to accomplish this:

1. Calculate total $ for the order (16,700*75.84/100 + 5,400*75.85/100 + 4,900*75.86/100 + 10,300*75.87/100) = $28,292.93
2. Allocate all clients except 1, based on the ratio quantities ordered / quantities filled:

Client 2 = $28,292.93 / 37,300 * 10,000 = $7,585,24 
Price = 7,585,24 / 10,000 * 100 = 75.8524.

Client 3 = $28,292.93 / 37,300 * 12,300 = $9,329.84
Price = $9,329.84 / 12,300 * 100 = 75.85235772

1. Calculate the last client as the remaining $$$:

$28,292.93 - ($7,585,24 + $9,329.84) = $11,377.85. 
Price = $11,377.85 / 15,000 * 100 = 75.85233333

Here I arbitrarily picked Client 1, the one with the largest quantity to be the object of the remainder calculation.